# Yii2 URL manager doesn't parse the rule

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to use Yii URL manager to rewrite URLs like `/site/about?tab=value` to `site/about/value` or `site/value`.

My rule `/<tab:\w+>' => 'site/about` doesn't work. Here is the full URL manager code:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' =>
        [
            '/' => 'site/index',                
            '/deals' => '/deal/deals',
            '/<tab:\w+>' => 'site/about', //my rule
            '/about' => 'site/about',
            '/<action:[\-\w]+>' => 'site/<action>',
            '/<module:\w+>'  => '<module>/default/index',
            '/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'  => '/<module>/<controller>/view',
            '/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>/<entity_id:\d+>'  => '/<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '/<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'  => '<controller>/view',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>/<entity_id:\d+>'  => '<controller>/<action>',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '<controller>/<action>',

            '/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '<controller>/<action>',
            '/<module:\w+>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '<module>/default/<action>',
            '/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>'  => '<module>/<controller>/index',

        ],
```

And here is the widget code:

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'items' => [
        ['label' => '1', 'url' => ['/site/about', 'tab' => '']],
        ['label' => '2', 'url' => ['/site/about', 'tab' => 'value']],
        ['label' => '3', 'url' => ['site/about', 'tab' => 'tariffs']],
        ['label' => '4', 'url' => ['site/about', 'tab' => 'team']],
        ['label' => '5', 'url' => ['site/about', 'tab' => 'documents']],
    ],
    'options' => ['class' =>'nav-pills nav-stacked c-nav'],
]);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand: Do you want to drop the query string (i.e. the url part after the `?`) from the URL whenever site/about is requested?

Comment: @tarleb, I wanted to transform urls like `/site/about?tab=value` to `/site/value` (and others with different tab values)  with this rule `/<tab:\w+>' => 'site/about`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use named parameters, but you are naming the module/controller part.
You can only use these 3 reserved words:

> module, controller, action

like the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html) examples:

```
[
    '<controller:(post|comment)>/<id:\d+>/<action:(create|update|delete)>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:(post|comment)>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:(post|comment)>s' => '<controller>/index',
]
```

But you are using `<tab:\w+>` that doesn't means anything for the rules section

Probably you could use:

```
'/site/about/<tab:\w+>' => 'site/about',
```

to catch URLs like:

> web.com/site/about/bla

And then in the controller you could use the `$tab` variable like

```
namespace app\controllers;

class SiteController extends \yii\web\Controller {
        public function actionAbout($tab)
        {
            return  $this->renderContent("Hello $tab");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u for the answer. I found out that it's ok to use named parameters either like `<tab:(about)>' => 'site/about` or `/about/<tab:(about|value|documents|tariffs|team)>' => 'site/about`.

Comment: Great to know that!  I saw your answer and will try that

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that some rules like `/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '<controller>/<action>` and `/<action:[\-\w]+>' => 'site/<action>` were parsed earlier than mine, so I changed them.
Here is my solution:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' =>
        [
            '/' => 'site/index',
            '<tab:(about)>' => 'site/about',
            '/about/<tab:(about|value|documents|tariffs|team)>' => 'site/about',
            '/<action:(index|login|logout|contact|signup|request-password-reset|reset-password|thank-for-register|connect-inviteduser)>' => 'site/<action>',
            '/<controller:(deal)>/<action:\w>'  => 'deal/<action>',
            '/<module:(trades)>'  => '<module>/default/index',
            '/<module:(trades)>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'  => '/<module>/<controller>/view',
            '/<module:(trades)>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>/<entity_id:\d+>'  => '/<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '/<module:(trades)>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '/<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'  => '<controller>/view',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>/<entity_id:\d+>'  => '<controller>/<action>',
            '/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '<controller>/<action>',
            '/<module:(trades)>/<action:[\-\w]+>'  => '<module>/default/<action>',
            '/<module:(trades)>/<controller:\w+>'  => '<module>/<controller>/index',

        ],
    ],
```

The widget code:

```
<?php
                        echo Nav::widget([
                            'items' => [
                                ['label' => 'О проекте', 'url' => ['/site/about', 'tab' => 'about']],
                                ['label' => '5 причин работать через портал', 'url' => ['/site/about', 'tab' => 'value']],
                                ['label' => 'Продвижение и тарификация', 'url' => ['site/about', 'tab' => 'tariffs']],
                                ['label' => 'Проектная команда', 'url' => ['site/about', 'tab' => 'team']],
                                ['label' => 'Документы', 'url' => ['site/about', 'tab' => 'documents']],
                            ],
                            'options' => ['class' =>'nav-pills nav-stacked c-nav'],
                        ]);
                        ?>
```

And the action code:

```
public function actionAbout($tab = 'about')
{
    $this->layout = '/about';

    $tab = $tab == 'about' ? 'index' : $tab;
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
        return $this->renderPartial('about/' . $tab);
    else
        return $this->render('about/' .$tab);
}
```